# Solr Query Syntax for 1 Item in an Array Field

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a solr index whose contents get populated with xml something like:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name='id'>1234</field>

        <field name='fileText'>fileId:1162052;fileName:blah_purchasing-policy.pdf; The parsed text of the file</field>
        <field name='fileText'>fileId:2502611;fileName:blah_leasing-policy.pdf; The parsed text of the file</field>
```

...

Note that the fileText field is an array type in my solr schema.

I was hoping to be able to find documents with documents whose file names contain leasing and those leasing files contain TBD using a query something like:

```
fileName:("fileName\: leasing"~5 AND TBD)
```

However IF there is a non leasing file whose text contains TBD then it will fetch the document even though the leasing file lacks it.

How can I isolate to strictly one element of a an array that meets 2 discriminators (in this case the fileName: leasing and the text TBD)

Comment: When you say "is an array type" in my Solr schema - what do you mean? There is no "array" type in Solr. The proper way to solve this is to index the fields as properties directly on your document, i.e. a field named `fileName`, one named `content`, one named `fileId`, etc.

Comment: Sorry... the actual type is text_general and it has the multiValued="true" which causes the xml output to appear as <arr name="fileName"><str>...</str><str>...</str></arr>
I was referring to the <arr/> output as array type. 
As far as solving it the proper way I am considering that but it'll take a while to re-index the volume of documents that we have and if there is a way to have a maleable forward compatible list of files for the record that they associate to and let us search how I want then that would obviate a lot of change and work
      <int>

Comment: If your `fieldText` is a typical `text_general` kind of field, you should be able to get this by passing "leasing TBD" in quotes. For example `q=fileText:"leasing TBD"`. Solr will return documents where the indexed value for a fileText has both tokens (which is different from using a boolean expression like `q=fileText:"leasing" AND fileText:"TDB"`)